# ListView:your content must have a listview whose id attribute is "android.R.id.list"

Tags: android, listview

I got a problem with ListView.My activity inherit `ListView` that has an `android:id="@android:id/list"` value set.I searched solution, but it did not work.
This is my configuration file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My OnCreate is here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_demo);
    listView = getListView();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = 
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map1.put("user_ip", "user_name");
    map1.put("192.168.25.3", "Maple");
    map2.put("user_ip", "user_name");
    map2.put("192.168.34.3", "Sonny");
    map3.put("user_ip", "user_name");
    map3.put("192.168.25.12", "Eric");
    list.add(map1);
    list.add(map2);
    list.add(map3);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.user,
            new String[]{"user_ip", "user_name"}, 
            new int[]{R.id.user_ip, R.id.user_name});
    this.setListAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}
```

Anyone help?

Comment: How have you initialized `listView`?

Comment: Yes, I initialized the ListView.the code:`private ListView listView = getListView();`

Comment: paste your activity class definition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you are initializing `listView` is wrong.

Change,

```
private ListView listView = getListView();
```

to

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

And if you are **setting the contentView**, you don't need to extend your activity to `ListActivity`

Comment: This is the the first time that I have asked a question in stackoverflow.And I am not good at English.So, if I make some mistakes in  my words, please forgive me. answer is accepted!! :)

Answer (score 0):

getListView() is specific method for ListFragment/ListActivity do you use one of those?
Remove:

> listView = getListView();

Comment: I should not use `listView = getListView();` to initialize the `ListView`.I change it to `listView = (ListView)findViewById("android.R.id.list")`, then it works.